AWS CloudFormation YAML template, !GetAtt not returning a value. Stack Build Error: "Attribute 'DefaultNetworkAcl' does not exist"
I'm constructing a small CloudFormation build in AWS with YAML. Currently, I've created a VPC, and a Subnet. The first process I am trying is to modify the inbound and outbound rules on the NACL created, when the VPC is created. This is where I am experiencing issues. Below is the YAML Template being used:
Resources:
  InboundRule:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !GetAtt CSETrainingSubnet.NetworkAclAssociationId
      RuleNumber: 1
      Protocol: -1
      RuleAction: deny
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  OutboundRule:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !GetAtt CSETrainingSubnet.NetworkAclAssociationId
      RuleNumber: 1
      Protocol: -1
      Egress: true
      RuleAction: deny
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  CSETrainingVPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.146.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
      EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Training VPC
  CSETrainingSubnet:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref CSETrainingVPC
      CidrBlock: 10.146.1.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: CSETrainingSubnet
Outputs:
  DefaultNetworkACLID:
    Description: "ID of Training VPC Network ACL"
    Value: !GetAtt CSETrainingSubnet.NetworkAclAssociationId

The issue is when I'm calling "!GetAtt CSETrainingSubnet.NetworkAclAssociationId" under InBoundRule OutBoundRule, and Outputs, I get the following error: "Attribute 'NetworkAclAssociationId' does not exist." (also shown in the screenshot)

Thie same Attribute 'NetworkAclAssociationId' does not exist. error generates whether I call !GetAtt using the Subnet Association, or the VPC.DefaultNetworkAcl association.
Ive also attached a screenshot showing the the NACL does indeed exist, along with the VPC, and subnet.

Ive tried grabbing the association from the Subnet creation, instead of the VPC creation due to a recommendation from ChatGPT, but that did not help. I also attempted to grab the association from the output's area, after everything else completed, but I still get the same error message.
Only thing I have not tried is potentially issuing a wait command, as that is the only other thing I can think of. I was unsuccessful in researching topics for this exact issue where !getAtt does not work when a resource was created successfully.

I believe this has to do with IAM Permissions. Its a very unhelpful error message at its core, but for testing, I applied Administrator policy to my CloudFormation template, changed the !getAtt back to CSETrainingVPC.DefaultNetworkAcl, and it worked. Now to hunt down the IAM permission causing the issue.

Look like the following two IAM commands are needed if your getting the above error:
"ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls"
"ec2:CreateNetworkAclEntry"

Answer to the above issue "Attribute 'DefaultNetworkAcl' does not exist" or "Attribute 'NetworkAclAssociationId' does not exist." Was that my IAM role that Cloudformation uses was missing the following permissions:
"ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls"
"ec2:CreateNetworkAclEntry"
if your going for least priviledge, these are necessary, and is not indicated well via the error message. Figured I would try and use the admin role for testing, and after using the admin role, the issue was solved. Thus, had to find the right permissions to add.
